# Python copying an entire workbook with XLRD, XLWT and XLUTILS

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I simply want to copy an entire workbook. There is information to be added later which I am having no trouble finding how to add the information to single cells etc... Yet I have not found a way to copy an entire sheet. Perhaps I'm overcomplicating this but any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently you already found `xlutils.copy`.  What about it is not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
ws = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')
ws.write() you can add data to your worksheet like this
```

Comment: So if I have an open workbook from xlrd and I want to copy it is what i'm asking. I know how to add data. I want to copy the entire workbook that I have open in XLRD.

Comment: I figured I could use the copy utility from xlutils to copy an entire worksheet over. I load the the xls file into a workbook object and then create a workbook and try to copy the information over. It looks like I will have to copy it row by row? That kind of eliminates the purpose of a copy feature imo.